Does valkey provide Ram to flash feature?
Redis Enterprise Software allows us to configure and tune the ratio of RAM-to-Flash for each database independently, optimizing performance for your specific use case.
https://redis.io/blog/redis-on-flash-now-3-7x-faster/
Is this feature available in Valkey?
I want to save data till the limit for saving data is reached and then for the next consecutive data, I want to save them inside a persistent memory.
When the memory load becomes normal, I want to the data from persistent memory be moved to the main memory automatically.
